# How to client side validate a lists child objects in MV3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

Ii have a model like below which is displayed in the view :

Model:

```
public class DisplayQuestionViewModel
{
    public List<Question> Questions = new List<Question>();
}

public class Question
{
    public List<Answer> Answers = new List<Answer>();
    public long GetSelectedAnswer { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public long SysId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
Question questions = new Question();
List<Answer> Answers = new List<Answer>();
Answers.Add(new Answer(){ SysId = 1, Name = "Test" });
Answers.Add(new Answer(){ SysId = 2, Name = "Test2" });
questions.Answers = Answers;

DisplayQuestionViewModel model = new DisplayQuestionViewModel();
model.Questions.Add(questions);
```

View:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count(); i++)
{
    var question = Model.Questions[i];
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => question.GetSelectedAnswer,
        new SelectList(question.Answers, "SysId", "Name") , "Please Select")

}
```

How would I validate the drop down to list to ensure an item has been selected?

Thanks.

Comment: Validate what?? You have not shown any code relating to a dropdownlist, and the model you have shown has no relationship to a dropdownlist.

Comment: I have updated/edited the post.

Comment: Just add a `[Required]` attribute to your `GetSelectedAnswer` property, and include `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` in the view. But your view code is wrong anyway and cannot work correctly - it wont even bind to anything.

Comment: It needs to be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Questions[i].GetSelectedAnswer, new SelectList(...), "Please Select")` with `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Questions[i].GetSelectedAnswer)`

Comment: if i have multiple questions with the required data annotation work for each drop down?

Comment: Yes, it just needs to be `[Required(ErrorMessage = "..")]public long GetSelectedAnswer { get; set; }` (but I suggest you rename it to just `SelectedAnswer` - the 'Get' prefix makes no sense in a property name)

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LAqgd3 - i have the code running but the form is always submitted even when please select is chosen.

Comment: You have not included the relevant scripts - `jquery-{version}.js`, `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` in the view

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pqz2C8 - i have added the scripts but it still does not validate?

Comment: You need to read my previous comments! Its `Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Questions[i].GetSelectedAnswer, new SelectList(...), "Please Select")`

Comment: And you still have not included `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`

Comment: Thanks for the help! Got it working. :)